# ASP.NET Web API: OAuth service provider

Tags: asp.net, rest, oauth, authorization, asp.net-web-api

I want to add OAuth authorization for my RESTful web API, which build on ASP.NET Web API. Preferably to be able to use [Authorize] attribute. Could you give me examples of creating own service provider or using some library?

Comment: I am not sure why you should ever want to do that. OAuth and OpenID protocols use several request with user interaction and rest is basically a single machine based request/response.
You can combine the ASP.NET membership provider with a library like DotNetopenAuth and use the ASP.NET session mechanism for authentication.

Comment: @AndrevanHeerwaarde could you give an example of "combine the ASP.NET membership provider with a library like DotNetopenAuth"? I found only this example - [ASP.NET MVC 2 OpenID web site](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/81153747-70d7-477b-b85a-0374e7edabef). But as I understand this template uses WCF web service as OAuth provider and a lot of unnecessary code for OpenID (which I do not need). I would like to see an example of using ASP.NET WebAPI with DotNetopenAuth.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, this is planned for the next drop (which will be a release candidate).  So if you can wait until then, you'll get this out of the box with demos/samples.

http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Roadmap

Since the code is open source, I'd suggest following [the codeplex project](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/) to see how it progresses.  This way you can leverage what gets built as it happens without having to wait for the official RC.

Comment: It looks like the RC is out - do you know if this was part of it? I still see it on the roadmap (which doesn't seem to be up to date).

Comment: I haven't checked the samples personally but they may be updated.  See this post for context: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/discussions/351122.